# Minimalist cherrypy website with PUT method

Tags: python, rest, cherrypy, put

I am trying to make a minimalist website that accepts exactly two requests. First a GET request on '/', which should reply some simple string. The second a PUT request on '/put_url' that accepts a chuck of data. Here is what I have so far:

```
import cherrypy

class Main(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hy?"

class Uploader(object):
    exposed = True
    def PUT(self, data):
        print "hello"
        print data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/put_url': {
            'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')]
            }
        }

    webapp = Main()
    webapp.put_url = Uploader()
    cherrypy.quickstart(webapp, '/', conf)
```

How do I get this thing to work? For some reason I can't figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: see [this example](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-7-give-us-a-rest) from documentation

Answer (score 1):

Add an accept header. To do this add a decorator to your PUT method.

```
class Uploader(object):
    exposed = True
    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def PUT(self, data):
        print "hello"
        print data
```

You may not always want to use text/plain as your accept header. It depends on your application.

to test you can use

```
curl -X PUT -d data=xyz localhost:8080/put_url
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing dispatchers on the same application.

For example moving the dispatcher to the root of the app an changing the Main object to have method as HTTP method you will have something like this:

```
import cherrypy as cp

class Main(object):
    exposed = True

    def GET(self):
        return "Hy?"

class Uploader(object):
    exposed = True

    def PUT(self, data):
        cp.log.error("hello")
        cp.log.error(data)
        return "The data {} has been puted".format(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': cp.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()
        },
        '/put_url': {
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')]
        }
    }
    webapp = Main()
    webapp.put_url = Uploader()
    cp.quickstart(webapp, '/', conf)
```

It is also possible to mix the default dispatcher an the method dispatcher, for example:

```
import cherrypy as cp

class Main(object):
    @cp.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hy?"


class Uploader(object):
    exposed = True

    def PUT(self, data):
        cp.log.error("hello")
        cp.log.error(data)
        return "The data {} has been puted".format(data)


class API(object):
    exposed = True

    def __init__(self):
        self.put_url = Uploader()

    def GET(self):
        return "Welcome to the API!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cp.tree.mount(Main())
    cp.tree.mount(API(), '/api', config={
        '/': {
            'request.dispatch': cp.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()
        },
        '/put_url': {
            'tools.response_headers.on': True,
            'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')]
        }
    })
    cp.engine.start()
    cp.engine.block()
```

Notice how the `API` object is mounted on `/api`. To `PUT` on  the `put_url` method just use the URL `/api/put_url`. The configuration sections used for the `cherrypy.tree.mount` is relative to the mount point, in this case `/api`.